# how to add time periods to get a total time period in R?

Tags: r, datetime, time

How to calculate the sum of some time periods?
For example, need to add `00:30:00`, `00:10:00` and `00:10:00` to get a `50` mins as `00:50:00`.
How to do that? Is there a function like sum?

Comment: maybe use: library(lubridate); hms("00:30:00") + hms("00:10:00") + hms("00:10:00")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options e.g.:

```
library(lubridate)
hms("00:30:00") + hms("00:10:00") + hms("00:10:00")

[1] "50M 0S"


library(chron)
x <- times(c("00:30:00", "00:10:00", "00:10:00"))
sum(x)
[1] 00:50:00
```